# empty × 2 after setState without mutating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting empty × 2 in my console after submitting my first form.

I'm mapping first the data here

```
const payload = values.data.map(item => ({
  category: 'leave',
  email: item.sfMember,
  type: item.leaveType,
  startDate: moment(item.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  startTime: moment(item.startTime).format('hh:mm A'),
  endDate: moment(item.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  endTime: moment(item.endTime).format('hh:mm A'),
}));
```

Then set it here
`setEmployeeLeave([...isEmployeeLeave, payload]);`

But I'm getting this in console. Is this normal?

[image]

Comment: Where you put your `console.log` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it is normal! If you wanna track or change the effects you might be interesting in use the hook `useEffect`. Check it out > https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Answer (score 0):

As the payload is an array and i think you want to merge two arrays and not to make two arrays, you can try this

```
setEmployeeLeave([...isEmployeeLeave, ...payload]);
```

considering isEmployeeLeave is an array

Hope it helps